# DBF to SQL Migration Utility - Best way to tackle solution

Tags: c#, exception, memory, data-migration, memory-management

I have a very long winded question. I have recently been given a task by my employer where I am to create a custom DBF to SQL migration utility in C# from 117 *.dbf files. Each table has approximately 40-50 columns and over 100 rows. (Eg. Property Management Database)

How I am tackling it is the following:

1. Convert a dbf file into a DataTable object.
2. Add the DataTable object to a `List<DataTable>` which is contained in the model object.
3. Bind list to a DataGridView for column viewing purposes.

This is all done in a background worker which works fine.

The next thing I need to do is allow the user to convert and save this list into a very large *.sql file (or optionally, migrate it directly to SQL Express). Again, this I attempt to do in a background thread.

This is where I run into problems. I have a method that accepts a DataTable object and returns a string. In it, I have a stringbuilder object which concatenates all the columns into a 'create table' statement and attaches the associated insert statements in order to include the data.

This method is executed in a loop while passing an instance of each DataTable from `List<DataTable>` stored in the model object.

Now this works fine up until about the fourth or fifth DataTable before an 'Out of Memory' exception is thrown. I am sure to initiate and dispose of any objects I am not using. I have even went as far as to change all my string concatenation to stringbuilder append logic to take advantage of the stringbuilders better memory management.

I am pretty sure that all my objects are deallocated and garbage collected, so I am assuming that the problem lies in the fact that I am storing all the 117 tables in a list of the model object. Whenever I need to access this list, I simply pass a reference to the model object. As soon as I start building an sql statement for all the tables, the combination between the DataTables list and the Stringbuilder object, it's running out of memory.

I neglect to inform that I am new to the industry as I am fresh out of college.  I have been programming for many years only until recently have I been following 'best practice'.  So my question is to all of you, am I tackling this project the wrong way?  Is there a better way to do it and if so, could you help shed some light as to what you would do in my place?

Comment: Correct.  The conversion between DBF to DataTables works fine. Just running out of memory as a result of a combination of storing a List of datatables and building a stringbuilder object.

Comment: Your not calling the ToString() method on the StringBuilder object multiple times are you, just at the end when you want to write the data to a file and create the .sql file?  When you concatenate strings without using the StringBuilder object it is horrible on memory.

Comment: Have you considered using SSIS?

Comment: The only point in time that I call the ToString() method on the stringbuilder is at the end of the method.

Comment: Eric - to be honest, I am fairly new to data migration. This is the first time I heard of SSIS. Are there any tutorials you recommend?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Are you calling the method 117 times, so .ToString() would run 117 itmes?  How much data memory wise is in each table 1K, 1MB, 10MB?

Comment: Rob4md - Actually, you may be onto something. At the moment, I return a string of the stringbuilder.ToString() method. But I call this method for each table, and within that, for each insert statement. This could very well be the issue. I am going to give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Rob4md - No. That doesn't seem to be the issue. When watching my Performance monitor, it pushes my memory over 3.14gb from 2gb. Not that this is really any help.  Are we able to post a link to postbin here or is that allowed?  I wanted to post my code but it's way over the comment character limit.

Comment: @JamesShaw You should absolutely be using SSIS for this.

Comment: I have been browsing the net regarding SSIS. Is SSIS an external tool or can I use it directly from C# as a component similarly to using the SQLClient assembly reference?

Comment: Going back to my initial question, this is more a question of, is there a better way to manage the datatables that are converted from the data retrieved in the dbf files?  At the moment, I am storing the data for each dbf file in a datatable and then storing that datatable in a List<DataTable>.  This is evidently not the way to do it but I couldn't figure out an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I did what made sense.  I simply wrote the SQL directly to file rather than write it to a string and then write that string to file.  This appears to have done the trick.  Not sure why I didn't think of it earlier.